# NIS+ Solaris 10, Master Server Setup

Tags: solaris, nis

this is my first time with NIS+ Naming Service.

I want to configure my host to be a master root server using this script

> /usr/lib/nis/nisserver -r -d doc.com.

And I got this error:

```
> ********        ********    WARNING    ********        ******** NIS+ might not be supported in a future release. Tools to aid the migration
> from NIS+ to LDAP are available in the Solaris 9 operating
> environment. For more information, visit
> http://www.sun.com/directory/nisplus/transition.html
> ********        ********    *******    ********        ********
> 
> This script sets up this machine "master" as an NIS+ root master
> server for domain doc.com..
> 
> Domain name             : doc.com. NIS+ group              :
> admin.doc.com. NIS (YP) compatibility  : OFF Security level          :
> 2=DES
> 
> Is this information correct? (type 'y' to accept, 'n' to change) y
> 
> This script will set up your machine as a root master server for
> domain doc.com. without NIS compatibility at security level 2.
> 
> WARNING: this script removes directories and files related to NIS+
> under /var/nis directory with the exception of the client_info
> NIS_COLD_START file which will be renamed to <file>.no_nisplus.  If
> you want to save these files, you should abort from this script now to
> save these files first.
> 
> WARNING: once this script is executed, you will not be able to restore
> the existing NIS+ server environment.  However, you can restore your
> NIS+ client environment using "nisclient -r" with the proper domain
> name and server information.
> 
> Do you want to continue? (type 'y' to continue, 'n' to exit this
> script) y
> 
> setting up domain information "doc.com." ...
> 
> setting up switch information ... switch configuration file already
> set to use NIS+.
> 
> killing NIS and NIS+ processes ... stopping nscd ...
> 
> setup NIS_GROUP environment variable ...
> 
> rm /var/nis files ...
> 
> running nisinit ... This machine is in the "doc.com." NIS+ domain.
> Setting up root server ... All done.
> 
> starting root server at security level 0 to create credentials...
> 
> running nissetup to create standard directories and tables ...
> doc.com.: NIS+ servers unreachable. couldn't create org_dir.doc.com.
> **ERROR: it failed to create the tables.
```

I looked for this error, and didn't find any solution.

Comment: Why NIS+?  Is this homework?

Comment: No, it's a self study for Naming Service Solaris 10 administrator

Comment: Unless you are going to work on a site still using nis+, studying it is essentially a waste of time. It is no more provided with the latest Solaris release. I would recommend exploring ldap as a naming service instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this from the oracle site:
[Common NIS+ Namespace Error Messages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4558/acerrmsg-6/index.html)

It contains the known errors and you gives you hints where to look for for the error.

For this particular one:

> Description: The NIS+ command nissetup failed to create the
>   directories and tables. Check your system console for system error
>   messages:
>
> If there is a system error message, fix the problem described in the
>   error message and rerun nisserver.
>
> If there aren't any system error messages, check to see whether the
>   rpc.nisd process is running. If it is not running, restart it and
>   rerun nisserver.
>
> Blockquote

So basically, check /var/adm/messages for errors and check if the rpc daemon is running:

```
ps -ef|grep rpc.nisd
```

If the ourput is empty then start the process.

Execute the command again and in another session or terminal do the following:

```
tail -f /var/adm/messages
```

Hopefully you will be able to see the error that is generated and take the proper action to fix the issue.